# Load default.el configured by libraries but not the user's init.el

Tags: init-file, start-up

As far as I understand libraries can define a `default.el` file that will be loaded on startup. I would like to run librarie's `default.el`, but not the init file of the user (e.g. in `.emacs/init.el`). Is it possible somehow to do that? I tried to start emacs with `-q` but it will not load the libraries at all. I also tried `-u fakeuser` and it kind of work except that I get an error about a non existant user `fakeuser` (of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Init File` says:

> ‘default.el’ ... is loaded whenever you start Emacs (except when you specify ‘-q’).  But your init file, if any, is loaded first; if it sets ‘inhibit-default-init’ non-‘nil’, then ‘default’ is not loaded.

So the same `-q` option which inhibits your init file also inhibits `default.el`. You therefore do need to also load it explicitly on the command line.

The simplest way to do this is with the `-l` option:

```
emacs -q -l default
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `emacs -q` does this (whereas `emacs -Q` doesn't load either your init file or `default.el` or `site-lisp.el`).

See the Emacs manual, node [Initial Options](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Initial-Options.html).

Oops, I guess that's not correct. Apparently `default.el` is not loaded with option `-q`: see node [Init File](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html).

But you might give it a try. File `default.el` doesn't exist, by default. Someone has to create it. If you have edit access to `site-lisp.el` then you could maybe do what you had intended for `default.el` there instead.

Or maybe (hopefully) someone else has a proper answer: how to get both `site-lisp.el` and `default.el`, but not your init file, loaded at startup.

Comment: Thanks. Oh I thought that each library was free to define its own default.el/site and that emas would charge them all…  and in fact there is a single library/file with this name. But I'm using home manager that does create a default file for me (i could certainly put that in site, but then since there is a single site file I guess I will need to edit a file own by root or at least find an elegant way to merge these files and I don't really like that). Acually, can I use maybe `-q --eval XX` to start the default file? If yet what should I put in XX ?

Comment: Hum I tried to run ` emacs -q --eval '(load-library "default.el")'` and it seems to kind of work. I'm just not sure why it does not starts the splash screen in that case while it does if I start it without `-q`. Is it supposed to be strictly equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do

```
emacs -q --eval '(load-library "default.el")'
```

and it seems to work… I am not sure though if it is strictly equivalent (maybe the libraries are loaded before default.el instead of after… if you have more information let me know)

Comment: Was that different to `emacs -q -l default` ?

Comment: @phils Oh this is quicker indeed and seems to work similarly. If you want you can add your own answer that I can accept.

Comment: Sure; done (if not quite immediately).